# How to raytrace triangular faces when camera is not at origin?

Tags: raytracing, 3d, pixel-graphics, ray

I've watched the [Pixar In A Box, Maths of Rendering Tutorial](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/pixar/rendering/rendering-2/a/rendering-lesson-brief) on Khan Academy. I've started writing a raytracing program and have come to the point where I must solve for `t` (the parameter for the parametric ray through the camera and a point on the view plane).

In the tutorial, this is done by simply substituting the parametric formula for each `x`, `y`, and `z` into the equation of the plane that the triangle lies on. This leaves a single unknown (`t`).

However, in all the examples and exercises that are given by the tutorial the camera is located at [0,0,0]. As I'm sure you'll understand, this is in many cases unrealistic. Because the camera is at 0, they simplify as follows:

$$i=\frac{1}{t}C+tP$$

becomes simply:

$$tP$$

Which makes for an easy solve. My question is when the camera is not at [0,0,0] should I:

1. Calculate the coordinates of the plane relative to the camera. (So the camera acts as if it is [0,0,0]
2. Solve the equation as a quadratic. I'm still confused a bit about why this is quadratic in the first place. Could someone explain this? And which solution do I use?

Of the two options, which is more acceptable for use in this community? Why? Is one more computationally efficient?

**Edit:**
I think I have found a solution as follows:
The parametric equation (which is effectively just a weighted average) is represented like this in the tutorial:

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{t}C_{x}+tP_{x}$$

But I realize now that is the same as:

$$x(t)=C_{x}+t(P_{x}-C_{x})$$

Which is dramatically easier to solve.

So my final question is, which of the three is the most acceptable way to solve for t? I'm assuming the third one.

Comment: Have you been misreading $1-t$ as $1/t$ this whole time?

Comment: Yeah for like 5 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I'm stupid, the whole problem was I thought it was `1/t` and it is actually `1-t` in parametric form. Hope this helps someone anyway.